# Не работают http/https запросы в андроид

Tags: java, android

На десктопе в приложении все работает.
В манифесте доступ к интернету добавил.
Такой использую метод:

```
public static String request(String url) throws IOException{ 

  URL obj = new URL(url); 
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); 

  connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connection.getInputStream())); 
  String inputLine; 
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 

  inputLine = in.readLine(); 
  response.append(inputLine); 
  in.close(); 
  String actual = response.toString().trim(); 
  return actual; 
 }
```

Comment: Каким именно способом выражается неработоспособность?

Comment: Надеюсь Вы в курсе, что в андроиде нельзя выполнять работу с сетью в основном потоке?

Comment: Для работы с сетью создавать отдельный поток?

Comment: Asynctask или библиотека aquery или подобные